# How to combine two streams?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm trying to learn/understand streams in java and have this piece of code:

```
List <Tag> tags = (classA.getTags() != null ? classA.getTags() : new ArrayList<>());
List <Integer> tagsIds = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4));
List<Integer> ids = tags.stream().map(Tag::getId).collect(Collectors.toList());
tagIds.stream()
      .filter(tagId -> !ids.contains(tagId))
      .forEach(tagId -> {
         Tag tag = new Tag();
         tag.setId(tagId);
         tags.add(tag);
       });
```

Please, give me a tip how I can combine two streams into one?

------- Added 23.08.2018 --------
If we get rid of `ids` variable it will improve a bit performance and code below perform as we work with `Set <Integer> tagsIds`, so no duplicates (e.g. if `tagIds` contains values (5,6,7,8,5,6,7) it will work only with (5,6,7,8)). Below the modified code:

```
List <Tag> tags = (classA.getTags() != null ? classA.getTags() : new ArrayList<>());
List <Integer> tagIds = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(5,6,7,8,5,6,7));
tagIds.stream()
      .filter(tagId -> !tags.stream().map(Tag::getId).collect(Collectors.toList()).contains(tagId))
      .forEach(tagId -> {
            Tag tag = new Tag();
            tag.setId(tagId);
            tags.add(tag);
       });
```

This modification has disadvantages like the complexity of reading and debugging code

Comment: `Stream.concat`, but where are you even adding two streams?

Comment: @nullpointer first: tags.stream() , second: tagIds.stream()

Comment: okay and where is `tagIds` initialised/declared?

Comment: @nullpointer updated the question

Comment: I'm not sure I see a reason to combine the streams.  They're doing distinct and discrete operations on different sets of data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
List<Tag> combinedTags = Stream
        .concat( // combine streams
                tags.stream(),
                tagIds.stream().map(Tag::new) // assuming constructor with id parameter
        )
        .distinct() // get rid of duplicates assuming correctly implemented equals method in Tag
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, if you have enough data working with a `Set` will be faster, I assume a `Tag` can't have duplicate ids... And you can do everything in a few steps:

```
tagIds.removeAll(ids);

// assuming there is a Tag constructor that takes an Integer
  List<Tag> newTags = tagIds.stream().map(Tag::new).collect(Collectors.toList())
 tags.addAll(newTags);
```

Comment: wondering, wouldn't the `ids` creation here anyway require working with another `stream` of the list `tags`?

Comment: from [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52450280/how-to-combine-two-streams/52450666?noredirect=1#comment91843780_52450280) the question was more about *avoiding* to use two `stream()`... but in your solution, you have included `ids` which I am assuming is created using the first `stream()` as in question(from the `List<Tag> tags`)...is that an incorrect inference on my part?

Comment: Why are you doing `tagIds.removeAll(ids);`? I don’t see a similar interaction in the OP’s code. In fact, I don’t see any interaction between `tagIds` and the rest of the code.

Comment: @Holger The code shared by Eugene seems to be handling the `filter(tagId -> !ids.contains(tagId))` part of the question with `removeAll`.

Comment: @nullpointer I was just confused by the number of declared variables and the lack of any problem statement from the OP. So using the my browser’s search function I didn’t notice that `tagIds` and `tagsIds` are likely supposed to be the same.

Answer (score 1):

The `Tag` class assumed as

```
class Tag {
    Integer id;

    Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    Tag(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

One way to improve the code may be looking for something like:-

```
List<Integer> ids = tags.stream().map(Tag::getId).collect(Collectors.toList());
tagIds.stream().filter(tagId -> !ids.contains(tagId))
               .map(Tag::new)
               .forEach(tags::add);
```

Unless your `Tag` class is comparable based on the `id` and then you can actually just use a single stream as -

```
List<Tag> tags = Arrays.asList(new Tag(5),new Tag(6)); //example
List <Integer> tagIds = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4); // from question

tagIds.stream().map(Tag::new)
               .filter(tag -> !tags.contains(tag))
               .forEach(tags::add);
```